# valgrind-3.13.0 unhandled instruction: 0xDEFF 0x1A9B?

Tags: valgrind

when i run valgrind-3.13.0 getting this below  unhandled instruction: 0xDEFF 0x1A9B

```
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4cdee24 (libc.so.6:calloc) redirected to 0x4837bc8 (calloc)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce30e4 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x4839afc (strncmp)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce698c (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x483d88c (strchrnul)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce3224 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x48395bc (strncpy)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4cde9c4 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4836ac0 (free)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce2f9c (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x483910c (strnlen)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce2411 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x483a414 (strcmp)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce4b60 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4839dec (strcasecmp)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce333c (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x483e3b0 (strpbrk)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce42dc (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x483c53c (bcmp)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4bc3841 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new(unsigned int)) redirected to 0x4835c68 (operator new(unsigned int))
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4bc1f19 (libstdc++.so.6:operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x4837120 (operator delete(void*))
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce3ce4 (libc.so.6:strstr) redirected to 0x483e200 (strstr)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4bc38c5 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new[](unsigned int)) redirected to 0x4836518 (operator new[](unsigned int))
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4cdead0 (libc.so.6:realloc) redirected to 0x4837e34 (realloc)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4bc1f25 (libstdc++.so.6:operator delete[](void*)) redirected to 0x4837780 (operator delete[](void*))
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce4bb8 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4839ea4 (strncasecmp)
--5896-- REDIR: 0x4ce2710 (libc.so.6:stpcpy) redirected to 0x483c6b4 (stpcpy)
disInstr(thumb): unhandled instruction: 0xDEFF 0x1A9B
--5896-- Caught __NR_exit; running __gnu_cxx::__freeres and __libc_freeres() wrapper
==5896== 
==5896== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5896==     in use at exit: 60,454 bytes in 3,246 blocks
==5896==   total heap usage: 3,667 allocs, 421 frees, 281,586 bytes allocated
```

Why does it occur ? does it need to patch valgrind?

Comment: Which platform and which compiler are you using?

Comment: armv7l GNU/Linux ,gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi

Comment: Can you try building your own Valgrind from the git repo?

Comment: i had done by building from git repo only  , tried with v0.3.13 , v0.3.12, v0.3.11